# Can't build project, have error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_JNI_CreateJavaVM"

Tags: java, c++, cmake, jvm, java-native-interface

Hello I have been tried to create JVM instance from C++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    JavaVMOption jvmopt[1];
    jvmopt[0].optionString = (char *) "-Djava.class.path=";

    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vmArgs.nOptions = 1;
    vmArgs.options = jvmopt;
    vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    // Create the JVM
    JavaVM *javaVM;
    JNIEnv *jniEnv;
    long flag = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&javaVM, (void**)
            &jniEnv, &vmArgs);
    if (flag == JNI_ERR) {
        cout << "Error creating VM. Exiting...\n";
        return 1;
    }



    javaVM->DestroyJavaVM();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to build my project(I am using CLion) build is finished with errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_JNI_CreateJavaVM", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(repl_native)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(repl_native ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I think in CMakeList must be presented linking for shared library jvm.dylib or something like that, but I don't know where is located and how add this linking to cmake. Also I am using macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing JVM libraries.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo027

I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but before you reject helping hand, take a look there ;)

This sample is prepared for macOS. It uses Makefile, but you can still pick up some settings - like libraries used for building the code.

Pay attention to:

```
-L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server/ \
    -ljvm \
    -rpath ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server
```

You can also find sample code with CLion here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNoD001

This is also not exactly what you are looking for, but still, maybe it will help.

Have fun with JNI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, cheers ;-)